# Laravel 5.1 MethodNotAllowedHttpException on store method using Resource Controller

Tags: php, rest, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am trying to add a record to a database utilizing a resource controller, however, am getting  MethodNotAllowedHttpException error.  I have gone through several similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29327047/laravel-methodnotallowedhttpexception-on-post-form) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32785670/methodnotallowedhttpexception-in-routecollection-php-line-219/35017080#35017080) ,however, none seem to answer me. This is my code:

Routes.php

```
Route::resource('animals', 'AnimalsCtrl');
```

Part of my model.

```
protected $table='animals';
protected $primaryKey='name';

protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'type'
];
```

The store method in the controller.

```
   public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $creature = $request->all();
        Animal::create($creature);

    }
```

This is the form.

```
        <form method="post">
            <div class="small-6 small-centered large-4 large-centered columns">
                {!! csrf_field() !!}
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Name</th>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="50" required>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Type</th>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="type" maxlength="20" required>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <button type="submit" class="button success">
                                <i class="fi-plus"></i>
                                Add Animal
                            </button>
                        </th>
                        <td>
                            <a href="{{url('/animals')}}" class="button alert">
                                <i class="fi-x-circle"></i>
                                &nbsp; Cancel
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Does anyone have any suggestion on how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are posting the form, what is the URL that you are posting the form to ? The url should be in the action . For example as follows

```
<form action="/animals" method="post">
</form>
```

Comment: If you think this answer has resolved your query , please mark this as an answer for people coming in next. - Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong but I think you are missing the action parameter in your form

Try this:

```
<form action="/animals" method="post">
```

Instead of this

```
<form method="post">
```

As a tip I suggest you use the HTML Forms facade. Check this out: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/10

Here's the documentation for Laravel 5.1 https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html